# Calling a function in main window with a button created in subwindow PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to make GUI application, using Pyqt5. The app has 2 windows: Main window with table widget and start button, and Subwindow that works like a stopwatch, with time as self.label and 2 buttons: "done" and "not done".
I want to make a function that checks which button in stopwatch (subwindow): "done" or "not done" was pressed and returns this information to a specific cell in table widget (main window).

To define a specific cell I created a global variable, which counts the number of both buttons presses.
This is the code:

```
global i
a = 0

class Stoper(QMdiSubWindow):
  
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Stoper")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 500)
        self.UiComponents()
        self.show()
  
    def UiComponents(self):
        self.count = 0
        self.flag = False
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setGeometry(75, 100, 250, 70)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("border : 4px solid black;")
        self.label.setText(str(self.count))
        start = QPushButton("Start (S)", self)                         
        start.setGeometry(125, 250, 150, 40)
        start.pressed.connect(self.Start)
        done = QPushButton("Done (Space)", self) 
        done.setGeometry(125, 300, 150, 40)
        done.pressed.connect(self.Done)
        done.pressed.connect(M.statusdone)
        ndone = QPushButton("Not Done (D)", self) 
        ndone.setGeometry(125, 350, 150, 40)
        ndone.pressed.connect(self.Ndone)
        ndone.pressed.connect(M.statusndone)
        timer = QTimer(self)                                            
        timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)                            
        timer.start(100)

    def showTime(self):
        if self.flag:
            self.count+= 1

        text = str(self.count / 10)+"/"+str(i)+".0"
        self.label.setText(text)
        if self.count >= i*10:
            self.label.setStyleSheet("background : light green;")
  
    def Start(self):
        self.flag = True

    def Done(self):
        self.flag = False
        self.count = 0
        self.label.setText(str(self.count)+"/"+str(i)+".0")
        self.label.setStyleSheet("border : 4px solid black;")  
        global a
        a+= 1
        if a>=10:
            self.close()


    def Ndone(self):
        self.flag = False
        self.count = 0
        self.label.setText(str(self.count)+"/"+str(i)+".0")
        self.label.setStyleSheet("border : 4px solid black;")  
        global a
        a+=1
        if a>=10:
            self.close()

class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Window'
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self.width = 620
        self.height = 700
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.tab_widget = MyTabWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tab_widget)
        self.show()
```

I created 3 tabs in main window, but since it is not the problem with the tabs, I skipped this part of code

```
class MyTabWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        
        self.table = QTableWidget(self.tab3)
        self.table.move(20,80)
        self.table.setRowCount(10)
        self.table.setColumnCount(4)
        self.table.setColumnWidth(0,50)

        self.Load_data = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab3)
        self.Load_data.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 10, 200, 50))
        self.Load_data.setText('&Start')
        self.Load_data.clicked.connect(self.show_Stoper)
        self.Load_data.clicked.connect(self.progress)

    def statusdone(self):        
        self.table.setItem(a-1, 0, QTableWidgetItem("done"))
        self.table.setItem(a, 0, QTableWidgetItem("..."))
    
    def statusndone(self):    
        self.table.setItem(a-1, 0, QTableWidgetItem("not done"))
        self.table.setItem(a, 0, QTableWidgetItem("..."))

    def show_Stoper(self):
        self.w = Stoper()
        self.w.show()
    
    def progress(self):
        global a
        self.table.setItem(a, 0, QTableWidgetItem("..."))

M = MyTabWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

As you can see, I made a function statusdone and statusndone, which i want to call with a buttons in stopwatch called "Stoper". To make it work, I have created Instance of a class MyTabWidget. Unfortunately it only gives me error in this line:
MyTabWidget.**init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'parent'
When i delete 'parent' from def **init**  and 'super', it returns error:
QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget
What should I do to make it work. Do I have to modify the classes?

Comment: Why are you creating instance of `MyTabWidget`? That instance has absolutely no use, and you should not even create it there, since it create the specific issue you're facing: QWidgets cannot be created before a QApplication instance (which you clearly create only *after* importing the other script. Also: 1. don't use globals; 2. use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html); 3. only classes and constants should have capitalized names, not functions and variables.

Comment: Could you explain why shouldn't I use global variables?

Comment: In general programming (especially OOP), it's preferable to always have a context for an object, either using a local variable or object members (instance or class attributes). Using global variables makes it difficult to understand where/what/when the variable has changed if more objects or functions access it at different times. It's also easy to make mistakes, especially when using generic or meaningless names like you did with `a`: as the program grows, you may easily forget about that, and use it for the wrong reason or in the wrong way. Just do a search for "why globals are bad".